Gradlee sync issue in Android studio
enter image description here
I'm totally new in Android studio. This is my final year project I have taken it from git. It says gradle dependencies cache may be corrupt. And your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version gradle requested by the project. And also the state of a gradle build.  so anyone can help me with this issue.


Stop Gradle Build Processes
Re-download Dependencies and Sync Project


This is not working
